# How to I interpret the graph for affected page for Page Indexing 5xx

Tags: google-search-console

Can you help me understand the page indexing 5xx graph. Based on the graph it looks like every day there are more than 60 5xx requests per day. But at the same time when I look at the crawl stats the number of 5xx per day is very less. So how to I interpret the graph when it has 65 pages affected for 5xx. Is it some form of cumulative number?

[image]

[image]